# Pipe Size from well to house

Tags: pump, pex, well, copper

I'm new to owning a house with a well and am looking to clean up piping and well equipment as it is all from the 70's and I'm experiencing strong sulfur smells in my water.

From the specs I've gathered my well is 1/2 HP about 80' deep in the well with static water level at 14'.

Pipe from the pump is 1" poly however by the time it makes it to my utility room under the slab the pipe goes down to 3/4" in copper.

is 3/4" inlet sufficient to up-size my existing 40-gallon pressure tank to an 80 gallon? I will probably be staying with 40/60 pressure switch.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

I lived in a house 20 years ago that had your exact installation. I lived there for 24 years and had no problem with water flow or water pressure. Since I do plumbing I thought I could improve water flow, big mistake, all that time wasted. It worked fine with or without my tinkering. The sulphur smell is probably iron. Have your water tested; Home Depot and Lowes have test kits. You take a sample and send it to a company. I would also get a second opinion from a local water softner co. Also ask your neighbors if they have the same water smell and ask how they addressed it. I had to get an iron filter and a softner from Culligan. The salesman was from the same town and had a great reputation. I was well pleased.

Comment: "The sulphur smell is probably iron."  No, it's not. Iron does not smell like sulfer.  Sulfer smells like sulfer.  In potable well water, the sulfer smell is likely to be hydrogen sulfide.

Comment: Nearly always. in well water, the "sulfur" smell is hydrogen sulfide that is produced near the well bore by sulfate reducing bacteria. The bacteria "eat" the sulfate in the water producing H2S. It is likely much less than 1 ppm so, not harmful. You can temporarily  stop it by putting bleach into the well  - killing some bacteria.

Comment: Pressure tanks with blown bladders can cause the bad smell also. If there are filters on the incoming lines when these get dirty they can also cause foul smells.